# Implementing a Map with the notion of Time

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, data-structures, time-complexity

I was recently challenged to implement a data structure with following two methods:

`set(key, value, time)`: sets key to value at the specified time.
`get(key, time)`: gets the value for key at the specified time or earlier.

If we set a key at a particular time, it will maintain that value forever or until it gets set at a later time.

### Examples

**Example 1**

```
d.set(1, 1, 0) // set key 1 to value 1 at time 0
d.set(1, 2, 2) // set key 1 to value 2 at time 2
d.get(1, 1) // get key 1 at time 1 should be 1
d.get(1, 3) // get key 1 at time 3 should be 2
```

**Example 2**

```
d.set(1, 1, 5) // set key 1 to value 1 at time 5
d.get(1, 0) // get key 1 at time 0 should be null
d.get(1, 10) // get key 1 at time 10 should be 1
```

**Example 3**

```
d.set(1, 1, 0) // set key 1 to value 1 at time 0
d.set(1, 2, 0) // set key 1 to value 2 at time 0
d.get(1, 0) // get key 1 at time 0 should be 2
```

Comment: So you want to keep a history of the changes? If so, your Question would be more clear if you said that explicitly.

Comment: No, It's not "history" that I'm tracking. Let's say a traditional map has a value for a key. If a new value is now introduced, the existed value is overwritten. Keeping track of these old values would be "tracking histories". My requirement is not related. Here the same key can have different values, at independently different times. Here time can be any comparable type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my implementation:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

/**
 * An Implementation a Map with the notion of Time.
 *
 * @param <K> the type of keys maintained by this map
 * @param <V> the type of mapped values
 * @param <T> the type of time tracked by this map.
 *            T MUST implement {@link Comparable} to have a notion of comparing times.
 * @author Hari Krishnan
 * @see Map
 * @see NavigableMap
 */
public class TimedMap<K, V, T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private final Map<K, NavigableMap<T, V>> map = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Associates the specified value with the specified key at the specified time in this map.
     * If the map previously contained a mapping for the key at this time,
     * the old value is replaced by the specified value.
     *
     * @param key   key with which the specified value is to be associated
     * @param value value to be associated with the specified key
     * @param time  time at which said association should occur
     */
    public void set(K key, V value, T time) {
        if (!map.containsKey(key))
            map.put(key, new TreeMap<>());
        map.get(key).put(time, value);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped at the specified time or earlier,
     * or {@code null} if this map contains no mapping for the key at the specified time or earlier.
     *
     * @param key  the key whose associated value is to be returned
     * @param time the time(or earlier) at which the values associated with the key is to be returned.
     * @return The value to which the specified key is mapped at the specified time or earlier, or
     * {@code null} if this map contains no mapping for the key at the specified time or earlier.
     */
    public V get(K key, T time) {
        try {
            return map.get(key).floorEntry(time).getValue();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Improvements and suggestions welcome!

Comment: Instead of the whole `if(!map.contains(key)) ...` you could replace the code in your `set` method with a one-liner: `map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new TreeMap<>()).put(time, value)`. Provided you're using Java 8+

Comment: Oh wow. I'm learning data structures and didn't know this existed! Thanks!

Comment: Don’t catch `NullPointerException` in this way. This will hide bugs. Using explicit `null` checks is not more complicated.

Comment: While I agree that a blanket catch of `NullPointerException` is bad, in my case the only possible places which return null is either the `get(key)` or the `floorEntry(time)`. In both cases, I gain no extra clarity by manually checking for a and returning a `null`. That was my consideration and thus I felt a one-liner like this will be more readable with no loss to clarity.

Comment: How can you tell by looking at your code that the `hashCode` and `equals` methods of `K` (invoked by `HashMap.get`) and the `compareTo` method of `T` (invoked by `TreeMap.floorEntry`) will never throw a `NullPointerException`? Besides that, your code is not a one-liner. Your code is a try-catch block spanning five lines.  It’s not simpler than, e.g. `var e = map.getOrDefault(key, Collections.emptyNavigableMap()).floorEntry(time); return e == null? null: e.getValue();`